# Add autogenerated C# file into solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, auto-generate

In C++ I can autogenerate some classes and then modify an empty cpp file to

```
 #include "myautoclass.cpp"
```

in the prebuild step and these classes will be compiled and linked. Is there a way to do this in C# in a prebuild step? I'm on VS2010. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of generating classes (and any other files) is by using [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

An excellent [set of tutorials can be found here](http://www.olegsych.com/tag/t4/).

Comment: I have used T4 myself. The built in editor in Visual Studio is horrible but once you figure out how to do it it is actually pretty nice. I recommend the free version of [Tangible T4 Editor plugin](http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html). It adds intellisense (for the core dll's only, you need to upgrade to pro for all assemblies) and code highlighting to visual studio.

Comment: Yes, I second that. Tangible did a fine job. You can add the editor by using the Extension Manager in Visual Studio 2010 under Tools.